# r for loop not iterating to each item

Tags: r, for-loop

**Problem:**

My for loop does not appear to be looping through my dataframe. I think this because it just prints out everything when it hits my debug print line. The code in the FOR works on its own

**Goal**

I want to run a correlation on all the groups in a rather large data set. This code is supposed to loop through a unique list of paths (var3) and run correlation on every path.

**Data frame setup:**

```
df.1 
id var1 var2 var3
1  23   2.1  "this"
2  32   2.2  "is"
3  13   2.3  "is"
```

**CODE**

```
# reduce size
directory.df$var1<-format(round(directory.df$var1/1000,1),nsmall=1)
directory.df$var2<- format(round(directory.df$var2/1000,1),nsmall=1)

df.1 <- unique(directory.df$var3)
df.1 <- data.table(unique.directories)

for (current.dir in df.1)
{
 print (current.dir) 
 directory.group <- subset(directory.df, var3 == current.dir)
 directory.group$var1<- as.numeric(directory.group$var1)
 directory.group$var2<- as.numeric(directory.group$var2)

 ## correlation ##
 cor(directory.group$var1, directory.group$var2)
}
```

When I run the code, the print(current.dir) will print out the entire list. It appears as if the first line of the for (current.dir in df.1) takes all the values for var3 and puts it in current.dir.

Comment: Get rid of `df.1 <- data.table(unique.directories)`

Comment: `for (current.dir in df.1)` will essentially loop over each column (of which there is only one in this case). That's because `df.1` is essentially a list, and each column is a element of the list.

Comment: Is the sample data `df.1` really `directory.df`? And is `df.1` just an array of unique values from `directory.df$var3`?  It's unclear what the input is or there is extra code that is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @Ista can you explain why that code was causing the weird behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to remove this line **df.1 <- data.table(unique.directories)**, and it worked.

```
#  reduce size
directory.df$var1<-format(round(directory.df$var1/1000,1),nsmall=1)
directory.df$var2<- format(round(directory.df$var2/1000,1),nsmall=1)

df.1 <- unique(directory.df$var3)

for (current.dir in df.1)
{
 print (current.dir) 
 directory.group <- subset(directory.df, var3 == current.dir)
 directory.group$var1<- as.numeric(directory.group$var1)
 directory.group$var2<- as.numeric(directory.group$var2)

 ## correlation ##
 cor(directory.group$var1, directory.group$var2)
}
```